# Need clarifications on a few lines of code in the mysqld_safe shell script

Tags: mariadb, mysqld-safe

I'm trying to develop a tool to check MariaDB option files to identify potential errors. When I was going through the `mysqld_safe` shell script in order to understand how it works,  I came across these lines (lines 505 to 536, to be exact):

```sh
MY_PWD=`dirname $0`
MY_PWD=`cd "$MY_PWD"/.. && pwd`
# Check for the directories we would expect from a binary release install
if test -n "$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION" -a -d "$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION"
then
  # BASEDIR is already overridden on command line.  Do not re-set.

  # Use BASEDIR to discover le.
  if test -x "$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/libexec/mariadbd"
  then
    ledir="$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/libexec"
  elif test -x "$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/sbin/mariadbd"
  then
    ledir="$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/sbin"
  else
    ledir="$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/bin"
  fi
elif test -x "$MY_PWD/bin/mariadbd"
then
  MY_BASEDIR_VERSION="$MY_PWD"      # Where bin, share and data are
  ledir="$MY_PWD/bin"           # Where mysqld is
#Check for the directories we would expect from a source install
elif test -x "$MY_PWD/libexec/mariadbd"
then
  MY_BASEDIR_VERSION="$MY_PWD"      # Where libexec, share and var are
  ledir="$MY_PWD/libexec"       # Where mysqld is
elif test -x "$MY_PWD/sbin/mariadbd"
then
  MY_BASEDIR_VERSION="$MY_PWD"      # Where sbin, share and var are
  ledir="$MY_PWD/sbin"          # Where mysqld is
# Since we didn't find anything, used the compiled-in defaults
else
  MY_BASEDIR_VERSION='/usr'
  ledir='/usr/bin'
fi
```

What confuses me first and foremost is the comment `# BASEDIR is already overriden on command line. Do not re-set`. *How* exactly is `$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION` set before that line to begin with? The only way (as far as I can tell) for `$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION` to be set to a user-provided value (either via command line options or an option file) is via the `parse_arguments()` function defined in lines 293 to 384.

```sh
parse_arguments() {
  for arg do
    val=`echo "$arg" | sed -e "s;--[^=]*=;;"`
    case "$arg" in
      # these get passed explicitly to mysqld
      --basedir=*) MY_BASEDIR_VERSION="$val" ;;
      --datadir=*|--data=*) DATADIR="$val" ;;
      --pid[-_]file=*) pid_file="$val" ;;
      --plugin[-_]dir=*) PLUGIN_DIR="$val" ;;
      --user=*) user="$val"; SET_USER=1 ;;
      --group=*) group="$val"; SET_USER=1 ;;
      --log[-_]basename=*|--hostname=*|--loose[-_]log[-_]basename=*)
        pid_file="$val.pid";
    err_log_base="$val";
    ;;

      # these might have been set in a [mysqld_safe] section of my.cnf
      # they are added to mysqld command line to override settings from my.cnf
      --skip[-_]log[-_]error)
        err_log=;
        skip_err_log=1;
        ;;
      --log[-_]error=*)
        err_log="$val";
        skip_err_log=0;
        ;;
      --port=*) mysql_tcp_port="$val" ;;
      --socket=*) mysql_unix_port="$val" ;;

      # mysqld_safe-specific options - must be set in my.cnf ([mysqld_safe])!
      --core[-_]file[-_]size=*) core_file_size="$val" ;;
      --ledir=*) ledir="$val" ;;
      --malloc[-_]lib=*) set_malloc_lib "$val" ;;
      --crash[-_]script=*) crash_script="$val" ;;
      --mysqld=*) MYSQLD="$val" ;;
      --mysqld[-_]version=*)
        if test -n "$val"
        then
          MYSQLD="mysqld-$val"
          PLUGIN_VARIANT="/$val"
        else
          MYSQLD="mysqld"
        fi
        ;;
      --dry[-_]run) dry_run=1 ;;
      --nice=*) niceness="$val" ;;
      --nowatch|--no[-_]watch|--no[-_]auto[-_]restart) nowatch=1 ;;
      --open[-_]files[-_]limit=*) open_files="$val" ;;
      --skip[-_]kill[-_]mysqld*) KILL_MYSQLD=0 ;;
      --syslog) want_syslog=1 ;;
      --skip[-_]syslog) want_syslog=0 ;;
      --syslog[-_]tag=*) syslog_tag="$val" ;;
      --timezone=*) TZ="$val"; export TZ; ;;
      --flush[-_]caches) flush_caches=1 ;;
      --numa[-_]interleave) numa_interleave=1 ;;
      --wsrep[-_]on)
        wsrep_on=1
        append_arg_to_args "$arg"
        ;;
      --skip[-_]wsrep[-_]on)
        wsrep_on=0
        append_arg_to_args "$arg"
        ;;
      --wsrep[-_]on=*)
        if echo $val | grep -iq '\(ON\|1\)'; then
          wsrep_on=1
        else
          wsrep_on=0
        fi
        append_arg_to_args "$arg"
        ;;
      --wsrep[-_]urls=*) wsrep_urls="$val"; ;;
      --wsrep[-_]provider=*)
        if test -n "$val" && test "$val" != "none"
        then
          wsrep_restart=1
        fi
        append_arg_to_args "$arg"
        ;;

      --defaults-group-suffix=*) defaults_group_suffix="$arg" ;;

      --help) usage ;;

      *)
        case "$unrecognized_handling" in
          collect) append_arg_to_args "$arg" ;;
          complain) log_error "unknown option '$arg'" ;;
        esac
    esac
  done
}
```

The problem is that `parse_arguments()` is first called on line 583 (*after* the aforementioned conditional tests). So how is it possible for `$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION` to get overriden on the command line before that?

To me, there are only three conceivable ways for this to occur:

1. `mysqld_safe` is re-run somehow after it was first launched (this is possible, but what would be the point in doing so?)
2. The user set the `MY_BASEDIR_VERSION` environment variable manually before launching the script.
3. The `MY_BASEDIR_VERSION` environment variable is set during MariaDB's installation process.

Having said that, these three possibilities lead to more questions than answers. I have gone through `mysqld_safe`'s documentation but came up empty. I hope somebody here can provide me with the clarification that I need.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: This is derived from [code](https://github.com/mariaDB/server/commit/c924f116f65d96818be88dae79018a83e19411b5) and [mysql bug 39326](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39326). It would be set in `parse_arguments` if applicable. Can you describe the scenario on which you are checking the configuration changes. There is hopefully something better than this rather antiquated script.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for commenting. I'm trying to write a simple tool that scans a `.cnf` (option file) file in order to identify possible issues with it. The tool will check each entry and option group inside the file and then tells the user or not whether or not the server can be launched without any issues.

Comment: @danblack Based on the diff in the first link you provided, it seems like that comment I mentioned applies to the deleted lines (bugfix) rather than the lines below it; hence the confusion. Having said that, I'm still unsure as to why we need that conditional test to begin with. In normal setups, the variable `MY_BASEDIR_VERSION` is not set until `parse_arguments()` is called. But `parse_argument()` is called after that conditional test. The only way this makes sense is if the user manually set `MY_BASEDIR_VERSION` in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of checks that can only be tested at runtime as it maps to the nature of the pre-installed instance.

What I would do as a check, is:

1. Install using previous configuration

```
    D=$(mktemp -d)
    mariadb-install-db --datadir=$D
```

2. change configuration to next configuration

```
    mariadbd --datadir=$D --socket=/tmp/x.sock
    for a in $(seq 10); do [ -S /tmp/x.sock ] && { echo  works; break; }; echo notyet; sleep 1; done
    rm -rf "$D"
```

3. if it exits early, there is a configuration error.

Both `mariadbd` and `mariadbd-install-db` accept `--defaults-file=name` as their first argument.

There's possibly still a few edge cases where some variable might depend on `datadir`, or the nature of hardware/os/filesystem. This should cover the common configuration typos or values out of range.